# PetaPOCO with MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, petapoco

I'm trying to test PetaPOCO with MS Access database.

Connection string in web.config

```
<add name="ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Data.mdb; Persist Security Info=False" providerName="System.Data.Oledb" />
```

Accessing MS Access database-

```
var db = new PetaPoco.Database("ConString"); //throws exception here
var rows = db.Query<Model>("SELECT * FROM Table");
```

Exception thrown-

```
"Could not match `System.Data.Oledb` to a provider.Parameter name: providerName"
```

Is there any way to do it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with PetaPoco version 5.1.127 or later, MS Access support is backed in and no custom DB provider is required.

Sample config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="msaccess" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Databases\MSAccess\petapoco.accdb" providerName="OleDb"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Fluent configuration

```
var builder = DatabaseConfiguration.Build().UsingConnectionName("MyConnection");

var db = builder.Create();
```

Constructor configuration

```
var db = new Database("MyConnection");
```

Comment: Because it's still in beta, the integration tests can be found in the [dev branch](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/tree/development/PetaPoco.Tests.Integration.x86/Databases/MSAccess)

Comment: The access provider does not support paging. However all the other APIs should work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by their documentation "Works with SQL Server, SQL Server CE, SQLite, MySQL, MariaDB, and PostgreSQL. (Oracle supported but does not have integration tests).", it doesn't support MS Access

To use it, you would need to write your own provider. Samples of providers can be found [here](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/tree/master/PetaPoco/Providers)

Comment: Thanks. I visited your link. I think it is useful. But it is an advanced level programming. Would you please help me with few snippets? I am using PetaPoco.Core.Compiled from nuget.

Comment: Hey mate. Track the progress here https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/issues/246

Comment: Access is supported in the latest beta

Comment: Dear Plebsori, Post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is this

```
using System.Configuration;
```

and

```
var db = new PetaPoco.Database(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConString"]);
```

Comment: thanks. I don't think it will work. It's provider related problem.